# EmberJS - keeping model in sync with data in localStorage

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My router looks something like this.

```
-Contacts
    -Details
-Dashboard
-Listings
```

Once a contact is opened (i.e, transitioned into `contacts.details`), that contact should be tracked under `recent contacts`. These `recent contacts` are then displayed in other routes like the `dasboard` and `listings`. I addedan action called `updateRecentContacts` inside the `ContactsDetailsController`. Here I am manually saving these contacts to the local storage.

```
APP.ContactsDetailsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {      
        updateRecentContacts: function(contact) {
            // Do some processing and then add it to localStorage
            // Note: store refers to a localStorage plugin. Not Ember Data
            store.set('recentContacts', recentContacts);
        }
    }
});
```

Because these `contacts` are to be displayed in various other routes, I added a property called `recentContacts` in the `ApplicationController` and set it's value to the data from the `localStorage`. Now I'm able to render these contacts in any route using the `render` helper and providing this `ApplicationController`'s contacts property as the model.

```
    App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        recent: {
            contacts: store.get('recentContacts')
        }
    });


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="recentContacts">
    {{#each contact in controllers.application.recent.contacts}}
        <!-- Render this template using {{render}} helper in any other view -->
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

This works but the data that is being rendered is out-of-date from the localStorage data. The correct data is only getting displayed after a hard refresh.

My question is, how do I keep this data in sync? I'm not even sure if I am doing this the right way. Surely, others must have come across a scenario where they need to keep track of something across routes (recent posts, articles etc.) more efficiently. I'm not using Ember Data as I'm not sure if it is worth using it just for this `recentContacts` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the property values of your ApplicationController manually to reflect your changes.

In your case I would do it like this assuming you don not want to change anything within your `details` (in my case `index`) controller.

Inject your application controller via the `needs` property. Basically the computed alias is optional but we like it fancy and shiny, don't we..

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  application: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application')
});
```

The ApplicationController could look like that:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  recent: {
    contacts: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
  }
});
```

The **important** part resides in ApplicationRoute. Here we handle the action which comes by due to embers event bubbleing. Here we can change the applications controller properties and if the data binding if correct it will be reflected all over the application.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    updateContacts: function () {
      console.log('Doing stuff in application route...')
      this.controller.recent.contacts.pushObject('gold');
    }
  }
})
```

The template looks like

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each application.recent.contacts }}
    <li {{action 'updateContacts'}}>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

To see it in action here is a jsbin for you: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dibep/1/edit

Comment: Hello Oliver, Thanks for your time. That works great. Because we are referencing the `ApplicationController` in the `details`, couldn't we just update the `recent.contacts` property directly there? I tried it and it seems to work as expected but not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: I'm sure there are pro and cons for both ways. Events encourage a more loosely coupled design whereas the method invocation ensures that no other instance along the bubbling path "accidently" consumes the event.